# With Proxy Pattern and Without Proxy Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, proxy-pattern

I have gone thru several examples but I didn't found any examples having displayed same example With Proxy Pattern and  Without Proxy Pattern,

Any one have a generic example ? by seen such example surely will understand do we really need Proxy Pattern to be used or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Proxy pattern is applicable whenever there is a need for a more versatile or sophisticated reference to an object than a simple pointer. Here are several common situations in which the Proxy pattern is applicable:

- control access to another object
- lazy initialization
- implement logging
- facilitate network connection
- to count references to an object

For a simple example let's consider a scenario where a group of wizards want to enter a tower but there is a proxy guarding the resource and allowing only three first wizards to pass.

```
public class Wizard {

    private String name;

    public Wizard(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}

public class WizardTower {

    public void enter(Wizard wizard) {
        System.out.println(wizard + " enters the tower.");
    }

}

public class WizardTowerProxy extends WizardTower {

    private static final int NUM_WIZARDS_ALLOWED = 3;

    private int numWizards;

    @Override
    public void enter(Wizard wizard) {
        if (numWizards < NUM_WIZARDS_ALLOWED) {
            super.enter(wizard);
            numWizards++;
        } else {
            System.out.println(wizard + " is not allowed to enter!");
        }
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WizardTowerProxy tower = new WizardTowerProxy();
        tower.enter(new Wizard("Red wizard"));
        tower.enter(new Wizard("White wizard"));
        tower.enter(new Wizard("Black wizard"));
        tower.enter(new Wizard("Green wizard"));
        tower.enter(new Wizard("Brown wizard"));

    }
}
```

Console ouput:

```
Red wizard enters the tower.
White wizard enters the tower.
Black wizard enters the tower.
Green wizard is not allowed to enter!
Brown wizard is not allowed to enter!
```

As requested, here is the same example code now with the `WizardTowerProxy` code merged into `WizardTower`.

```
public class Wizard {

    private String name;

    public Wizard(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class WizardTower {

    private static final int NUM_WIZARDS_ALLOWED = 3;

    private int numWizards;

    public void enter(Wizard wizard) {
        if (numWizards < NUM_WIZARDS_ALLOWED) {
            System.out.println(wizard + " enters the tower.");
            numWizards++;
        } else {
            System.out.println(wizard + " is not allowed to enter!");
        }
    }
}

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WizardTower tower = new WizardTower();
        tower.enter(new Wizard("Red wizard"));
        tower.enter(new Wizard("White wizard"));
        tower.enter(new Wizard("Black wizard"));
        tower.enter(new Wizard("Green wizard"));
        tower.enter(new Wizard("Brown wizard"));
    }
}
```

Console ouput:

```
Red wizard enters the tower.
White wizard enters the tower.
Black wizard enters the tower.
Green wizard is not allowed to enter!
Brown wizard is not allowed to enter!
```

Comment: thanks for reply , 
I was expecting 2 examples side by side comparing without proxy implementation and with proxy implementation.So for the above example , **implementing "only three first wizards to pass" constraint/condition inside single classed example** (i.e. **all written inside Wizard class**) **would be the NON PROXY EXAMPLE I guess ???**

Comment: @Sanjeewa I have added another example that has the same functionality, this time without the proxy.